Logs Not Flowing from Function App deployed under ASE to its own Application Insights
We are experiencing an issue where logs are not flowing from our Azure Function App to Application Insights. The Function App has been deployed under an App Service Environment (ASE), and the APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING environment variable has already been set, but the logs are not appearing in Application Insights as expected.
Additionally, also tried Host.json updating with logging parameters but there was no success.


    {
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host": "Information",
      "Function": "Information",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Information"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableDependencyTracking": false
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}

ASE VNet has been configured with default NSG outbound rules.
Function Code - this same code is working in our other envt but without ASE and we could see the logs under invocations etc.
import logging
import os

import aiohttp
import arrow
import azure.functions as func
from shared.event_hub import EventHubProducer

VERSION = "1.3.4"
EVENT_HUB_SEND_SLEEP = 1  # In seconds
HOURS_OF_HISTORY = 2

logging.getLogger("azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger("azure.eventhub").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

data_url = (DATA_URL)
device_url = (DEVICE_URL)


async def get_data() -> tuple[dict, dict]:
    """Download data from BCC API"""
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(connect=10)) as session:
        async with session.get(data_url) as resp:
            result = await resp.json()
            logging.info(f"DATA: {result}")

        async with session.get(device_url) as resp:
            devices_result = await resp.json()
            logging.info(f"DEVICES RAW: {devices_result}")

        return result["records"], devices_result["records"]


def create_parsed_records(sensor: str, data_records: list[dict], device_map: dict[str, str]) -> dict | None:
    """Create parsed records for the specified device/sensor"""
    sensor_data = {item["fields"]["measured"]: item["fields"][sensor] for item in data_records}
    # logging.info(f"Sensor data: {sensor} {sensor_data}")

    metric = "precipitation" if device_map[sensor] == "Rainfall" else "level_mahd"
    # logging.info(f"METRIC: {metric}")

    readings = []

    for key, value in sensor_data.items():
        if value == "-":
            continue

        reading = {"Key": metric, "Value": {}}

        reading["Value"]["timestamp"] = arrow.get(key).int_timestamp * 1000
        reading["Value"]["value"] = float(value)
        reading["Value"]["timespan"] = 5 * 60 if metric == "precipitation" else None

        readings.append(reading)

    if readings != []:
        parsed_record = {
            "key": f"bcc-{sensor.lower()}-dev",
            "docType": "ParsedRecord",
            "deviceId": f"bcc-{sensor.lower()}-dev",
            "readings": readings,
            "traceId": None,
            "timestamp": max([item["Value"]["timestamp"] for item in readings]),
        }
        parsed_record["id"] = str(parsed_record["timestamp"])
        return parsed_record


async def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    try:
        # Get one big dump of data and device definitions
        data_records, device_records = await get_data()
        logging.info(f"Retrieved {len(device_records)} devices and {len(data_records)} historical 5-minute rows")

        # Create a map of sensor id to sensor type (Rainfall vs Stream Height)
        device_map = {item["fields"]["sensor_id"].lower(): item["fields"]["sensor_type"] for item in device_records}

        eventhub_client = EventHubProducer(
            fully_qualified_namespace=os.environ["EVENTHUB_PARSED_FQDN"], eventhub_name=os.environ["EVENTHUB_NAME"]
        )

        # Fetch a list of available sensors from the header of the last entry
        # and then iterate for each sensor through all records, only picking data from that sensor in each iteration
        # Send to event hub each time a parsed record is constructed for a sensor
        for sensor in list(data_records[0]["fields"].keys()):
            if not sensor.startswith("e"):
                continue

            parsed_record = create_parsed_records(sensor, data_records, device_map)

            if parsed_record:
                await eventhub_client.send_events([parsed_record], sleep=EVENT_HUB_SEND_SLEEP)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
    finally:
        await eventhub_client.aclose()


Provide your function code.

Is there any special setup with firewalls, DNS, private link? Can you log into the advanced tools/kudo go to the console and try to do some DNS lookups, tcpping on the app insights DNS records https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/ip-addresses#outgoing-ports

Deploy the Function to the function app with Container Apps Environment using below command:
az functionapp create --name <APP_NAME> --storage-account <STORAGE_NAME> --environment <Containerapp_Environment> --workload-profile-name "Consumption" --resource-group <resource_group_name> --functions-version 4 --runtime dotnet-isolated --image <LOGIN_SERVER>/<Image_name>:<tag> --assign-identity

I have deployed the sample function to the Azure functionapp created with Container Apps Environment:

Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.11

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

Able to run the functions as expected:

host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  }
}

Application Insights logs:


